# What should I put in UserDTO and why?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, backend

I have a `User` entity as following:

```java
package com.yogesh.juvenilebackend.Model;

import jakarta.annotation.Generated;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userName;

}
```

What fields should I create inside the `userDTO` and why? What unique constraints I should add into the DTO?

I have currently made this DTO:

```java
package com.yogesh.juvenilebackend.DTO;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Setter;


@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class UserDTO {
    @NonNull
    private String userName;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String email;
}
```

What should I change in it? Also, what annotations I should add in `UserDTO` and `User` member fields and what constructors I should add?

Comment: The question isn't what should go in the DTO based on the entity - The question is what fields you need in the DTO for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTO, which stands for Data Transfer Object, is a container for data. It has no logics and only has getter and setter functions. For example, let's say getUser() returns information about the user. Then getUser() return DTO containing information of username, name, and email and you can access them with getter and setter.

Comment: Should I not add password and id field in DTO. What if my email and username are not unique. Then how will I edit db according to the DTO recieved from frontend

Comment: 1. DTO is just a container for data. If you think adding a password and id is more efficient, then add fields for them.
2. As I said before because DTO is just a container, db doesn't necessary to be changed according to DTO

Comment: @ThugLife - if those fields need to be stored in the database, then yes.  Otherwise no.  The DTO is the container for passing data from the front end to the database.

Comment: If fields are required to be unique, then the database should have uniqueness constraints.  And the business logic (in the front end) may also need to be aware of this in some way.